# Undocumented behaviour related with body, json and form parameters in got Node module

Tags: node.js, node.js-got

[Got module documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/HEAD/documentation/2-options.md#body) states that:

> If `body` is specified, then the `json` or `form` option cannot be used.

What does "cannot" mean in this context? The code explodes with an exception raise? Or one of them (either `body` or `from`/`json`) is ignored?

What about the same between `json` and `form`? What happens if I try to use both at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can tell with a quick test, e.g.:

```js
import got from "got";

(async () => {
    try {
        await got.post("http://localhost:3000", {
            body: "foo=bar",
            json: { foo: "bar" },
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
})();
```

`got` yells at you if you provide more than one of `body`, `form` or `json`:

```
RequestError: Expected value which is `undefined`, received value of type `string`.
```

this is a bit cryptic, but there's a hint further down the traceback that it's unhappy about the JSON:

```
    at Options.set json [as json] (file:///path/to/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/options.js:656:20)
```